# help with alias sql

Tags: sql

i am trying to learn about alias in sql for my course however i do not fully understand the command. As part of the work i must do this:

1. Understanding Complex SQL Queries
   (a) Select all columns / fields from master tracks and sound engineer joining the two based on the sound engineers ID and using an alias for each table.

i have got to here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s 
INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY,s.SOUND_ENG_ID;
```

but now i am stuck please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT * FROM  SOUNDENGINEER  s INNER JOIN  MASTERTRACK m ON   m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;
```

this seems to work

Comment: It's the same. The `AS` keyword is optional and both versions should work, unless you're using some odd database that somehow prefers NOT to use `AS`. I know of no such database though. o_O

Comment: i believe it is oracle every time i used AS i got an error seems to work now. thanks for all your help it put me on the right track

Answer (score 5):

It's correct but ON clause should be like this On m.EDITED_BY=s.SOUND_ENG_ID;

```
SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s 
 INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;
```

Comment: when i input this i get this error:                               SQL> SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s 
 INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;     
SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Did you include the * in the end of your query? "SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID; SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s" is pretty legal query dude, so remove the last * from you query if that's the case.

Comment: SELECT * FROM  SOUNDENGINEER  s INNER JOIN  MASTERTRACK m ON   m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID; seems to work

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM SOUNDENGINEER  INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK  ON MASTERTRACK.EDITED_BY = SOUNDENGINEER.SOUND_ENG_ID;

Comment: THIS wroks but i must use alias the other ways give me a command not ended error.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right. Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s 
INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;
```

Your use of the comma might suggest you were trying the alternate equi-join syntax, which would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s, MASTERTRACK AS m 
WHERE m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;
```

I prefer the former though, as you are explicitly stating that you are joining the tables with an `INNER JOIN` statement.

Comment: i get the same error : SQL> SELECT * 
FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s 
INNER JOIN MASTERTRACK AS m ON m.EDITED_BY = s.SOUND_ENG_ID;   
FROM SOUNDENGINEER AS s
                   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended