# SQL Simple alias bug

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I have a simple table Employee with columns employee_name, job, salary and dept_no.

The following query works :

```
SELECT ENAME, JOB, SAL FROM EMP WHERE (ENAME, JOB, SAL) = (SELECT ENAME, JOB, SAL FROM EMP WHERE ENAME = 'FORD');
```

But this one throws an error "T3 invalid identifier", what is wrong in my syntax? :

```
SELECT ENAME AS T1, JOB AS T2, SAL AS T3 FROM EMP WHERE (T1,T2,T3) = (SELECT ENAME,JOB,SAL FROM EMP WHERE ENAME ='FORD');
```

I am very confused because I have followed the syntax explained here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Please note that I am using Oracle, therefore I also tried to remove the "as" as I've read that it might be the issue : [help with alias sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366081/help-with-alias-sql)

P.S: I know this query can be reduced, I just want to understand the syntax problem.

Comment: Column alias does not apply until the end of the query. Use original name in the where

Comment: The `as` is only an issue for table aliases, not column aliases. But you can't use a column alias in the same level of query, except in the order-by clause. You can still use the real column names in your where clause, even though they aliased in the select list.

Comment: It's easier to think about if you remember that the alias is used to push the name out once the row has been returned. That could be to the client, a higher level query or even the ORDER_BY of the same query (the ORDER BY is applied after the rows are returned).